# Recommend a way to throw an exception if a getline delimiter isn't entered?

Tags: c++, string, delimiter, getline

I'm getting a line, eg
`Array has size: 4`
from cin and I want to firstly check the string is exactly this, and secondly extract the integer.
 I've found ways to read the string and extract the integer:

```
    string start;
    getline (cin, start, ':' );

    if (start != "Array has size")
    {
        throw MyException("Wrong format");
    }
```

but my problem here is that if the line read has no `:` in it then it just keeps waiting for one and the program is stuck. I can't check the string `start` to make sure it has a `:` in it because if there is one it's been consumed by the `getline`.

I can't get the `getline` to read 14 characters as I believe that is only possible with a `char*`?
 Is there a clean way to do this, I'd like to throw an exception if the string doesn't match without it getting stuck. Does it involve stepping through the string somehow? The other questions I've found don't seem to address this exactly.
 Any direction much appreciated!

Comment: That's kind of the point of a delimiter. Since you are testing for that character, it just won't stop collecting into start. Alternatively, you could first get the line from `cin` using the normal delimiter (`\n`) and then parse the resulting string later.

Comment: Could you have the user press enter instead, collect the string that way then check it for a delimeter? If none exists, output an error then ask for the string again? Or more simply ask for the size of the array without requiring them to write "array has size"

Comment: "I can't get the getline to read 14 characters" Well you can use `cin.width(14)`, but it will still get stuck if the input is less than 14 characters.

Comment: @cpplearner Thanks. As you say, not useful here, but useful to know!

Comment: Unrelated: I probably wouldn't throw an exception for this. Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional events, and the bag of carbon and water banging away at the keyboard hitting the wrong button is far from exceptional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `std::getline()` without a delimiter to read the entire line into a `std::string`, then use a `std::istringstream` to parse the line as needed, eg:

```
string line;
getline (cin, line);

istringstream iss(line);

string start;
getline (iss, start, ':');

if (start != "Array has size")
{
    throw MyException("Wrong format");
}

int number;
if (!(iss >> number))
{
    throw MyException("Wrong format");
}
```

Comment: This works well, thank you. Longer than I was hoping for, but much better than the parsing I was coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget `std::scanf`:

```
#include <cstdio>

std::size_t s;
if (std::scanf("Array has size: %zu", &s)) { 
    // ...
}
else {
    throw MyException("Wrong format");
}
```